# Python package "click" causes "Error: Got unexpected extra arguments (sdist bdist_wheel)" when used in new package

Tags: python, package, click, python-wheel

I am attempting to create a Python package that can be used as a terminal command. My setup.py file looks like

```
import setuptools

# If the package is being updated (and not installed for the first time),
# save user-defined data.
try:
    import checklist
    update = True
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    update = False

if update:
    import os
    import pickle
    dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(checklist.__file__), 'user_settings')
    files = {}
    for file in os.listdir(dir):
        files[file] = pickle.load(open(os.path.join(dir, file), "rb"))

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="SampleName",
    version="0.2.0",
    author="Author1, Author2",
    author_email="email@email.com",
    description="words words words.",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/samplesample/sample1",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 (GPLv3)",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        checklist=checklist.checklist:cli
    ''',
    python_requires='>=3.7',
    package_data={"checklist":["user_settings/*.pkl"]},
    include_package_data=True,
)

if update:
    for key in files:
        pickle.dump(files[key], open(os.path.join(dir, key), "wb"))
```

When I attempt to create the `checklist` package with the command

```
python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

I get the message

```
Error: Got unexpected extra arguments (sdist bdist_wheel)
```

When I remove `click` from my environment, the wheel is created without a problem. This seems strange because my code uses `click`.

```
import os
import sys
import csv
import click
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
from contextlib import suppress
import pickle


class UI:

    def __init__(self):
        <set variables>...

    <some methods>...

# noinspection SpellCheckingInspection
class Checklist(UI):

    def __init__(self):
        <set variables>...

        # start the process...
        while self.step_index < len(self.to_do):
            with suppress(ExitException):
                self.step()

    def step(self):
        self.__getattribute__(self.to_do[self.step_index])()
        self.step_index += 1
        self.overwrite = False

    <some methods>...


@click.command()
def cli():
    Checklist()

cli()
```

What could be causing this? How do I fix it?

Comment: Is there some code before the call to `setuptools.setup(…)`? Can we see the code? What about modules used in the code? Hard to debug without seeing code and full traceback.

Comment: @phd I added some more detail, but don't want to make the post overwhelming. The only output other than the error message was a suggestion to try "setup.py --help".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's amazing how a few small deviations from the best practice are chained together producing a major problem. :-)

The problem with `click` is the following. If `click` is installed your `setup.py` imports the module you shown us above. And the module **when imported** runs `cli()`, said `cli()` calls `@click.command()` and that parses the command line (intended for `setup.py`, not for `click`) and produces the error.

If `click` is NOT installed your `setup.py` tries import `checklist` and failed with `ModuleNotFoundError`. The exception is caught and ignored in `setup.py` and setup continues.

To fix the problem make `checklist` a module that can be both run (to call `cli()`) and imported without calling `cli()`:

```
def main():
    cli()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```